# What is the best practice of storing single use user settings in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns

I am struggling to find a pattern for storing single use user settings (VAT percentage, tag line. Things that are 1 off by nature) in Rails 3. I need to set up global site settings, which have single instances.

Ideally, I want the answer to be a design pattern, rather than a gem or plugin (unless someone knows a gem or plugin that integrates will with Active Admin)

Comment: How can the answer be a design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by single use settings?  Do you mean things like API keys and environment variables?

If so, then a good practice is to use the ENV hash, and set up ENV variables in the environments file (explained below).

Create a `.rb` file for each individual gem (or arbitrary entity) that needs settings in your `config/initializers/` directory.  For example, when using stripe, I created `config/initializers/stripe.rb` shown below:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
    :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

This sets up initial settings within my stripe gem, and pulls the variable values from the ENV hash.

To set variables in the ENV hash, you can do so within the `config/environments` directory.  In that directory, you will have three different files: `config/environments/test.rb`, `config/environments/development.rb`, `config/environments/production.rb`.  Setting variables in the ENV hash(as shown below).

```
AppName::Application.configure do
  # Set Stripe API Key
  ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] = "sk_test_key"
  ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] = "pk_test_key"

  ...
end
```

Comment: Sorry, no I mean things that are user editable. Taglines, VAT amount. Things like that.

Comment: I'm curious why you can't just add the user's settings as columns in the User table....or create a model called Settings that the user has_one of and belongs_to the user?

Comment: Because the settings are not related to User, or any other model. They are global settings, but user definable.

Comment: It sounds to me like these are settings that are particular to each and every user on the site, which means they should be entered into the User model (or in another table with a belongs_to relation back to the User model).  Settings that are not in the User model, but stored in the Rails configuration, would be applied to the *whole app*, and not particular to each user.

Comment: is this or something like a CRM where the admin can decide site wide parameters and many people will be deploying your rails app?

Comment: Sort of. Not really, but that's logically similar enough for this to make sense.

Comment: Well, then I would need to know more details as you are being very vague...  Site wide rails configuration settings should be set in initializers and not accessible by Users.  Users should *not* be able to change the Rails environment.  This presents security risks as well as being bad practice.  Users should be manipulating things in your database, which should be represented by models.  There is no logical reason to do it any other way.

Comment: Site wide setting, like blocks of text. Subheadings. Side wide navigation options, colours etc etc

Comment: And why are you averse to putting this into a Settings Model?

Answer (score 0):

How about a class for storing your key-value pairs?

```
class Settings < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :lookup, :value

  def self.VAT
    return self.find_by_lookup('VAT')
  end

end
```

Then you can do `@vat = Settings.VAT.value` or similar. The lookup is your internally defined key. Of course the value column will have to be all the same datatype, but you can handle any necessary transformation in the getter methods (or through subclasses).